# Google Sheets Script Calculator

Tags: google-sheets

I need help with a 'basic script'. I need it to work with 3 different cells beside each other (D2, E3, and F2)

- D2 will display my current inventory number on my rack.
- E2 end of day my employee will enter a number, press enter and it needs to subtract from the total amount in D2. Then return E2 back as an empty cell.
- F2 when i have inventory arrive it needs to be the opposite of E2 and add a value in D2. I will put a number, press enter, and D2 will add the value and return F2 back as an empty cell.

Any thoughts?

I am expecting a live data end of day sheet to accurately track inventory.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your current script, details of the current issue of your script, and the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I don't have a script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood about `I don't have a script.`. And, I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Ok , please re-read the post.